# Graph .h file and .cpp file im getting many errors

Tags: c++, graph

I have this code:

```
using namespace std;
struct nodeT;
struct arcT;


class Graph
{
public:

Graph(string xd);

    void addnode(string name,float xval,float yval);
    void addarc(string n1,string n2,float dist);
    void printarcs();
private:
    struct graphT
    {
        vector<nodeT *>nodes;
        vector<arcT * > arcs;
        map<string,nodeT * > nodemap;
    };
    struct nodeT{
        string nodename;
        float x,y;
        vector<arcT * > arcs;
    };
    struct arcT{
        nodeT * start;
        nodeT * finish;
        float distance;
    };
    void arcfinal(nodeT * a,nodeT * b, float len);
    graphT * g;
    //graphT *g=new graphT;
};

//#include "BST.cpp"

#endif



#include "Graph.h"


Graph::Graph(string xd)
{
g=new graphT;

}

void Graph::addnode(string name,float xval,float yval)
{
    //if(!nodemap[name])

    nodeT *t=new nodeT;
    t->nodename=name;
    t->x=xval;
    t->y=yval;


    g->nodes.push_back(t);
    g->nodemap[name]=t;

}

void Graph::addarc(string n1,string n2,float dist)
{
    nodeT * t1=g->nodemap[n1];
    nodeT * t2=g->nodemap[n2];

    arcfinal(t1,t2,dist);
    arcfinal(t2,t1,dist);

}

void Graph::arcfinal(nodeT * a,nodeT * b, float len)
{
    arcT * d=new arcT;
    d->start=a;
    d->finish=b;
    d->distance=len;

    g->arcs.push_back(d);
    a->arcs.push_back(d);
}

void Graph::printarcs()
{  
    for(arcT * curr=g->arcs.begin();curr != g->arcs.end();++curr)
    {
        cout<<curr->start->nodename<<"-----"<<curr->finish->nodename<<"----"<<curr->distance<<endl;
    }
}

//#endif
```

And I am getting this error:

> projects\graphsearch\graphsearch\graph.cpp(21) : error C2664: 'std::vector<_Ty>::push_back' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'Graph::nodeT *' to 'nodeT *const &'....

Can anyone please debug it?

Comment: If the code does not compile, you cannot debug it.

Comment: it does compile ....im getting the error ive mentioned in the title

Comment: That is a compiler error, so I cannot see how the code can compile.

Comment: wat do u suggest...im stuck on it for long

Comment: Does it work when you remove the forward declarations for nodeT and arcT at the top?

Comment: no it thorows more errors if i remove them.....theres only that 1 problem that its not being able to convert the ptr to a ptrconst& ...

Comment: Thanks a lot Seth that worked wonders......Thank You..it worked well....

Answer (score 1):

There are at least three errors.

The first is that `struct`s can be nested, and you have global declarations of `nodeT` and `arcT`. They are in the global namespace, so you're making vectors of `::nodeT*`, but the real structs are `Graph::nodeT*`.

Move the declarations from the top to inside the struct under the `private:`. That's the proper way to forward-declare them.

The second is that `begin` <strike>may or may not</strike> does not return an `arcT*`, you should use `auto`.

The third is that `begin` returns an iterator to the element, so you need to dereference it to get to the pointer, then dereference it again to get to members, like

```
cout << (*curr)->start->nodename << "-----" << (*curr)->finish->nodename << "----" << (*curr)->distance << endl;
```